# problem with SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm getting this `SMTP` error when using the new phpmailer release:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

I've tried using `SSL` instead of `TLS` with port number 465 and I've set gmail to allow less secure apps, none of this has made a difference is there something I'm missing?

Here's the code:

```
class gmail_xoauth
{
    public static function sendMail($subject,$body,$address)
    {


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

//Fill in authentication details here
//Either the gmail account owner, or the user that gave consent
$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$clientId = 'clientid';
$clientSecret = 'clientSecret';
//Obtained by configuring and running get_oauth_token.php
//after setting up an app in Google Developer Console.
$refreshToken = 'refreshToken';
//Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
$provider = new Google(
    [
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    ]
);
//Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth(
        [
            'provider' => $provider,
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
            'username' => $email,
        ]
    )
);
//Set who the message is to be sent from
//For gmail, this generally needs to be the same as the user you logged in as
$mail->setFrom($email, 'me');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($address, 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/examples/contentsutf8.html'), __DIR__);
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file

$mail->addAttachment('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/examples/images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
}
}
```

yes I have the client id and secret here's the full error:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a9sm1354888otc.75 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2600:1700:760:3400:794a:d1c1:d15d:e94d]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2600:1700:760:3400:794a:d1c1:d15d:e94d]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection a9sm1354888otc.75 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/TroubleshootingEmail sent!
```

Comment: Have you actually set up the access tokens that go in `$clientId`, `$clientSecret` and `$refreshToken`? Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` and post what it says.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Did you remove some of the debug output? It goes straight from EHLO to an auth failure, when it doesn't show you sending an AUTH command.

Comment: no I didn't this isn't it? AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8

Comment: No, that’s the server describing its capabilities. There should be an `AUTH XOAUTH2` command going from client to server.

Comment: I changed encryption to $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
and now I get this : SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Comment: do you have any idea what the problem is I've looked online but couldn't find anything I haven't tried yet